# FB.login is unresponsive

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am hitting a brick wall with this Graph API. I do not receive the alert box, yet the console shows no error. Might anyone understand what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<body>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'XXX',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.6'
        });

        FB.login(function(response) {
            // handle the response
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        }, {
            scope: 'public_profile,email'
        });

    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }

    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    };
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: all I'm trying to do is return the email and id.

Comment: any movement in the network tab to show that `sdk.js` is even loading?

Comment: Nothing in this code queries Facebook for the email or ID. You're only logging the user in - which, after the first time, will be silent, no authorization popup, as they've *already* authorized.

Comment: so, run a check login status?

Comment: it's coming up undefined. doesn't the social button use FB.login()?

Comment: The FB Login button plugin? No, that has no connection to FB.login.